# Set only one item to the listview's Adapter

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I want to send to adapter only one item from my custom ArrayList. When Activity starts, I send only one item. Then I want to implement gestureListener to my Activity and if I detect swipe up or down Action, I send to the adapter another item. How can I implement this?

I have my custom ArrayAdapter, where I pass my List. But I want to sent only one item:

```
public class InteractionsAdapter extends  ArrayAdapter<Message>{

  Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;    
List<Message> messages = null;
private Activity activity;
public InteractionsAdapter(Context context,  int layoutResourceId,List<Message> messages) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, messages);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.messages = messages;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    InteractionHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {

        (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.interactions_item, parent, false);

        holder = new InteractionHolder();
        holder.interactionId= (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.interactionId);
        holder.interactionAbove = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.interactionAbove);
        holder.interactionBelow = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.interactionBelow);
        holder.interactionMessage = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.interactionMessage);
        holder.interactionDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.interactionDate);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (InteractionHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Message message = messages.get(position);
    Log.i("in doinbackground",Integer.toString(messages.size()));

        Log.i("position",Integer.toString(position));

        holder.interactionId.setText(Integer.toString(message.getMessageId()));
        holder.interactionAbove.setText(Integer.toString(position));
        holder.interactionBelow.setText(Integer.toString(messages.size()-position-1));
        holder.interactionMessage.setText(message.getMessageBody());
        holder.interactionDate.setText(message.getMessageDate().toString());

    return row;
}

static class InteractionHolder
{
    TextView interactionId;
    TextView interactionDate;
    TextView interactionAbove;
    TextView interactionBelow;
    TextView interactionMessage;

}

}
```

I tried to do it with ArrayAdapter, passing only one item, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Give us some code to look at and we'll help you to refine it.

Comment: So you're sending an array with one item into your InteractionsAdapter?  Can you show us the code you use to setup your adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, simply adding  an

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 1;
}
```

and it works properly.